# Android Firebase Auth compile error

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to include Firebase Authentication in my Android app, but when I compile my program I get the error

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzp
```

Changing the version from 11.8.0 to 11.2.2 worked, but I need to use Firestore, which only has 11.8.0, and the two are incompatible. Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Is there a conflicting file I need to delete?

Comment: Can you try updating your firebase-ui-auth dependency to the latest version? (Currently 3.2.1 )

Comment: you are forced to use firestore because you implemented it, there is no need to implement firestore if you are doing database from firebase, you can use compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes, that solved it.

Comment: @NathanStewart if the answer helped, please upvote it and mark it as correct, so future viewers and know that it is helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this:

```
  implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

to this:

```
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'
```

Also there is no firebase 11.2.2, I think you meant 11.4.2 which is compatible with the above firebase ui version.

The firebase version 11.8.0 is compatible with firebaseui 3.2.1

You can check this table here:  https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Comment: There used to be a [version 11.2.2](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#sdk_version_1122_september_05_2017)